# If empty statement - checking variable - Ruby on Rails 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to connect my app to twilio and check if user that is sending sms is in the database. I have simple create action and depending

- if user is in the database finding him/her by its own number:
  statement A (working on its own - I have checked it), and

  user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From])
- if user is not in the database: statement B (working on its own - I have check it).      Then it picks up general user.

  user = User.find_by_friendly_id("xxxx")

I do not know how to make both work depending on statement. I try something like this, but it does not work:

'''

def create

```
user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From])

    if user.empty?

    user = User.find_by_friendly_id("xxxxxx")
    reply = params[:Body]
    post = Post.find_by_friendly_id("xxxxx")
    post.comments.create(user: user, reply: reply)

    else

    user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From])
    reply = params[:Body]
    post = Post.find_by_friendly_id("xxxxxx")
    post.comments.create(user: user, reply: reply)

    end
```

end

'''

### Thank you for your help.

this is the code I have right now

'''
def create

```
user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From])

    if user.blank?

    user = User.find_by_friendly_id("xxxx")
    reply = params[:Body]
    post = Post.find_by_friendly_id("xxxxx")
    post.comments.create(user: user, reply: reply)

    else

    reply = params[:Body]
    post = Post.find_by_friendly_id("xxxxx")
    post.comments.create(user: user, reply: reply)

    end
```

'''

Statement A, if user is in the database meaning first line and else statements get through, Statement B as well.

Comment: `User.find_by_friendly_id` is in both branches of the `if`, but your question states that you're using `User.find_by`, is that correct?

Comment: in case of statement B, when user is not in the database, I assign "general/global" user, which is found by user.find_by_friendly_id, in case of statement A, I try to look for the user in the database first using user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From]). I have twice user = User.find_by(phone: params[:From]), I erased the one from else statement, but it still does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what "does not work" mean, but try replacing the if condition to `user.blank?`, because if there's no user with the given `params[:From]` then `user` will be nil, and nil does not implement `empty?`. If you have any error it'd be worth adding it to your question